# PIT Mutation testing on apache commons math shows line coverage and mutation coverage as 0%

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, mutation-testing, pitest

I am trying to use PIT Mutation testing with maven for apache common math tests.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.pitest</groupId>
    <artifactId>pitest-maven</artifactId>
    <version>0.29</version>
    <configuration>
        <targetClasses>
            <param>org.*</param>
        </targetClasses>
        <targetTests>
            <param>org.*</param>
        </targetTests>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I added this to my **pom.xml** and `mvn org.pitest:pitest-maven:mutationCoverage`. I am able to run it but index files show Line Coverage and Mutation Coverage as 0%. I think I am not giving the parameters correctly. Moreover I need to mutate one test of apache-common-math  For e.g.  LUDecomposition.

Comment: 0.29 is quite old - there were some bugs fixed. Use 1.1.0. Do you get any errors in the output? You can share the output with Gist or Pastebin.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/3pMyViti.  I tried with version 1.1.0 that ends more abruptly. Here is the error with version 1.1.0 http://pastebin.com/wdXmig1h.

Comment: `org.*` is very wide scope - PIT's classes also match (`org.pitest`). As I suggested in my answer you can just omit those 2 parameter for basic analysis or define it as `org.apache.commons.math3.*`.

Comment: What do you mean by "mutate one test of"? If you mean you only wish to create mutations for a specific class then set targetClasses to org.apache.commons.math3.linear.LUDecomposition and targetTests to org.apache.commons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before running of mutation testing analysis run `mvn test` to compile main and test classes (and by the way verify that all tests pass which may affect PIT results).

After `mvn clean` or on a freshly cloned repository PIT doesn't have any classes to mutate and you can get mentioned message.

By default PIT plugin for Maven takes groupId as a base package, so for commons-math it is ok to completely omit a configuration section. Also update PIT version to 1.1.0 (or newest when available) to not hit already fixed bugs.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/0N6NXe70 This is error I am running into after executing mvn test, and then running mutation analysis. How can I prevent memory heap space error.

Comment: Use `jvmArgs` (PIT configuration) parameter to increase -Xmx. See [that](http://pitest.org/quickstart/commandline/) for the reference.